# Add Multi line text field to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, text, metadata, field

I am trying to add a multi-line text field to a document within Sharepoint but can't currently figure out how to do it.  Below is the code i have which works for most of the fields.

```
SPFile file = folder.Files.Add(*snip*);
    file.Item[guid] = stringValue;
    file.Item.SystemUpdate(true);
```

The document adds with no issues the problem is just adding multi line meta data to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-line fields (such as Keywords) simply expect a carriage return + new line pair to separate out each line:

```
SPFile file = folder.Files.Add(*snip*);
file.Item["Keywords"] = String.Format("One{0}Two{0}Three", Environment.NewLine);
file.Item.SystemUpdate(true);
```

Comment: Seems i was thinking a bit to complex.  Should of realized that myself i was trying to pass it arrays and all sorts.  Thank you.